# Internal Error 500 jbuilder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

I'm trying to render some json in my rails app using jbuilder, but the output is showing up as:

```
{"status":"500","error":"Internal Server Error"}
```

Here's the url:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/v1/appusers/10
```

Here's the controller:

```
module Api
  module V1
    class AppusersController < ApplicationController
      respond_to :json
      skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

      def show
        @appuser = Appuser.find(params[:id])      
      end
```

And my show.json.jbuilder file:

```
json.extract! @appuser, :user_auth_token, :id
end
```

I've never encountered this before with jbuilder and all of my other jbuilder files work just fine. Any idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to documentation, you don't need the `end` in the `jbuilder` template, just:

```
json.extract! @appuser, :user_auth_token, :id
```

Alternatively, if you are using a `Ruby` version major than 1.9, you can use this syntax:

```
json.(@appuser, :user_auth_token, :id)
```

Comment: I had tried taking off the end (but that threw an error). Using that new syntax worked like charm though!